# Recover EFS with aws start-restore-job in OneZone

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-backup

I didn't find the AvailabilityZoneName parameter in the startRestoreJob SDK
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Backup.html#startRestoreJob-property
For this reason, when I restore the snapshot, it is created as REGIONAL.
The AWS console itself allows you to select this when you restore. Does anyone know a solution?
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I was confronted with the same problem. the documentation seems not aligned. i check on cloudtrail but i have a HIDDEN_DUR_TO_SECURITY_REASONS placeholder...
But in Developper mode on chrome you can see metadata attribute sent to the server. so you need to use availabilityZoneName and singleAzFilesystem parameters.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `file system type` information in the startRestoreJob API in the Metadata property.

To the the values allowed, you can call the `GetRecoveryPointRestoreMetadata` API to get the Metadata value for your Recovery Point, and then use the values you get to pass to the `StartRestoreJob` API.

Docs for the GetRecoveryPointRestoreMetadata API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/API_GetRecoveryPointRestoreMetadata.html

Comment: I was calling GetRecoveryPointRestoreMetadata. It returns the property "metadata" which contains only two fields:
"aws: backup: request-id" and "file-system-id". Nothing else. I suspect that this property was forgotten to be documented.